# residue of $\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I first expanded the equation into $\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$, then I apply the theorem that
$$\underset{z=i}{Res}\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow i}(z-i)\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{2i} $$ but the correct answer should be $\frac{-i}{2}$, which step is wrong?

Comment: $\frac{-i}{2}=\frac{1}{2i}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{1}{i} = -i$, since $i^2 = i \cdot i = -1$.